# Ruby - get nth Character from string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the 5th to 7th Character from #{vm} however I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing?

```
puts "#{Colorable.wrap_color("Restarting VM's", :BLUE)}"
change_set.vms_to_restart.each do |vm|

puts "JH 0 - " + %x{hostname}
host_code = %x{hostname}[7,9]
vm_code   = #vm[5,7]   <---- THIS DOES NOT WORK

puts "JH 1 - #{host_code}"
puts "JH 2 - #{vm_code}"
puts "JH 3 - #{vm}"

  puts "Restarting ... #{vm}"
exit 1
  vm.restart
end
puts " "
```

Output:

```
Restarting VM's
JH 0 - qdscild401
JH 1 - 401
JH 2 -                    <---------- BLANK
JH 3 - qdcld401.vm10
Restarting ... qdcld401.vm10
```

Comment: How about `vm_code   = "#{vm[5,7]}"`

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: The above vm_code   = "#{vm[5,7]}"  gives me this error:

./do_changes.rb:76: undefined method `[]' for #<Core::VM:0x7fce138d4468> (NoMethodError)
        from ./do_changes.rb:72:in `each'
        from ./do_changes.rb:72

Comment: Am i using an older version of ruby?

Comment: Your question and comment contradict. Do you get that output, or the error message? Which?

Comment: I have added: vm_code   = "#{vm[5,7]}"

This gives me the following error output:

Restarting VM's
JH 0 - qdscild401
./do_changes.rb:76: undefined method `[]' for #<Core::VM:0x7f0e431a3468> (NoMethodError)
        from ./do_changes.rb:72:in `each'
        from ./do_changes.rb:72

Comment: This error hints to the fact the `vm` is not a `String` (it is a `Core::VM`)

Comment: The latest version of Ruby is 2.3. That should enable you to answer your question, "Am i using an older version of ruby?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
vm_code   = #vm[5,7]
```

everything after the `#` is a comment. Therefore, that statement is effectively:

```
vm_code = nil
```

The line should be

```
vm_code   = vm[5,7]
```

Or if the `vm` object is not a `String` you could try

```
vm_code   = vm.to_s[5,7]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, `vm[5,7]` means get the sixth character and the six additional characters after it (for a total of seven characters).

So

```
vm = 'abcdefghijklmno'
vm[5,7]
=> 'fghijkl'
```

If you only want the FIFTH character to the SEVENTH character

```
vm[4,3]
=> 'efg'
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I didn't realise

Comment: @CarySwoveland as usual well-spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Ah nice - I tried

```
vm_code   = vm.to_s[5,7]
```

But it hasn't trimmed off everything after the 7th Character

```
Restarting VM's
JH 0 - qdscild401
JH 1 - 401 
JH 2 - 401.vm1          <----- NOT TRIMMED after 7th
JH 3 - qdcld401.vm10
Restarting ... qdcld401.vm10
```

Comment: "I am trying to get the 5th to 7th Character from #{vm}" so of course everything after the 7th character will be trimmed off !!!!!

Comment: Yes but it HASN'T trimmed it off

Comment: Ah because it needs to be: vm_code   = vm.to_s[5,3]

Comment: What you have written here should be a comment on @ReggieB's answer. It most definitely is not an answer. You should delete it. Why someone upvoted is beyond me.